# How to create wake-up task on Win 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute some apps always when the machine wake up on the mornings.

Tried to create Scheduled tasks like below, but it didn't work, when i wake up the machine, nothing happens.

What can i do ?

[image]

Comment: Can you start the Apps in a simple batch file?  If so, just use Logon Scripts  (Group Policy).

Comment: @John yes, i can create a .bat file calling all the apps i need... but it won't work if the scheduled task don't run after waking up

Comment: Use GPedit Logon scripts and that will work. I do not recommend Task Scheduler for what you are trying to do.